# Two side-by-side squares are inscribed in a semicircle. The diameter of the semicircle is 16. What is the sum of the two squares' areas?

Tags: geometry, circles

Two side-by-side squares are inscribed in a semicircle. The diameter of the semicircle is $16$. What is the sum of the two squares' areas?

This is a bonus question from my online math class that I've been trying to solve but haven't gotten very far. I named $CD$ $x$ and $HD$ $y$, then drew $OB$ and $OF$, then did the Pythagorean theorem to try to get $x^2+y^2$ but I didn't have much luck with that.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I think it probably has to do with [this](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/geometry/perpendicular-from-any-point-of-a-circle-on-a-diameter-is-a-mean-proportional.html)

Comment: Take the specific case where the squares are congruent. The solution in that case is trivial.

Comment: @DanielMathias But then you would still need to show that the sum is independent of $D$.

Comment: @Teepeemm This is an online thing, it's probably just a field where you type in the answer.

Comment: All the solutions given (and indeed the question, I suppose) assume that length OD <= length OA. If the right hand square is inscribed within the semi circle and becomes bounded by C0 constrained to r, the solution is not independent of D.

Comment: @PhilH - $OA$ is as large as $OD$ can get. The maximum size the large square can be is when it is inscribed in the semicircle, (Which fixes the location of $D$, so the solution cannot depend on $D$'s location in this case.) Shrinking the square from that causes the center to move right, since $B$ is necessarily on the circle, but $C$ need not be.

Comment: @PaulSinclair no Phil is correct and you are wrong. If it helps the point being made is that rather than inscribing a second square on the *left* of ABCD as in the diagram above, you could inscribe it on the *right* of ABCD, in the space ABN. It would then clearly be possible to make the area of the two squares as small as desired by moving the point A closer towards N, so it's definitely not a constant area in that case either.

Comment: @CRDrost - $ABCD$ are corners of the *larger* square, with $DGFH$ the corners of the smaller square and $G$ being the point lying on $CD$. In the picture, the larger square is on the right, and I used that view in describing my answer. But it is just a matter of which side you are looking at, and is *immaterial* to the behavior and answer to this problem. Relabeling the corners so that you can argue doesn't change the truth of the matter, and doesn't in any way contradict the answers offered.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I did not relabel ABCD, nor move it anywhere. I put DGFH somewhere different than where it is on the above diagram.

Comment: Put another way, ABCGFH forms a non-convex 6-gon sharing the long flat side AH with the flat part of the semicircle. Over all of the pairs of scale factors that leave ABCD a larger square than DGFH, two families of inscriptions in the semicircle exist: those for which the proof works (A and F touch the circle, C does not) and those for which the proof doesn't (C and F touch the circle). PhilH is correct to state that the latter family obviously exists and obviously cannot satisfy the required area relation.

Comment: @CRDrost - yes you did. All answers and my comments were made per the labeling given in the OP. Such a labeling is very clearly always possible, Putting the small square on the other side is obviously just flipping the picture over, which does not in any way change the discussion. But your change exchanges the roles of $AB$ (the side of the large square opposite the small square) and $CD$ (the side of the large square shared with the small square). Your demand that comments made about the given labeling must also apply to your relabeling or be considered wrong, is just not a valid argument.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that is where you are wrong. If you leave ABCD in the exact place it is in the diagram and try to cram that exact DGFH square on the right hand side, it absolutely will not fit inside the semicircle. It will if you slide ABCD to the left but the moment you do that you have misunderstood the point. The point is that without sliding ABCD, another square of vastly smaller area can be placed in that space ABN. This changes the topology of the problem and invalidates all of the proofs below, as it must, because that square is vastly smaller than the one the proof prescribed.

Comment: For what it's worth I think you can save the statement by saying, instead of “a semicircle”, “the smallest possible semicircle” perhaps?

Comment: No, scratch that. There is potentially a third topology of inscription where B, C are on the circle but F is not and in some circumstances that is the smallest semicircle which the two squares can be inscribed in, as any attempt to put B, F on the circle puts C outside of it.

Comment: @CRDrost - Your statements have nothing at all to do with what I was saying. I was talking about applying labels to a diagram in accordance to the interpretations discussed in this thread (something that is always possible), and you accuse me of fixing a square in one exact place and cramming another "exact" square in? What does that have to do with anything. It is certainly nothing I was talking about.

Comment: @paulsinclair It is the entire point. Of course you are not talking about it; if you were talking about it you would not be wrong: but you are not talking about it, so you are. You still don't understand that B is not necessarily on the circle, which is where you were wrong above. And even in the cases when it is on the circle, sometimes F is not. Either is sufficient to invalidate the proof.

Comment: @CRDrost - The question is about two squares *inscribed* in the semi circle. If $B$ is not on the circle, then you can shift the pair in that direction, giving room to make them bigger until a point reaches the circle again. A figure is not inscribed if you can fit a larger similar figure inside. For the pair of squares to be described as inscribed, both $B$ and $F$ have to be on the circle.

Comment: @PaulSinclair By that definition triangles are not always inscribed in their circumscribed circles (if they are obtuse). I take that as an absurdity; whatever "inscribe" means, surely a polygon is inscribed in its own circumcircle, if that circumcircle exists. Also even if you make that change to the problem, PaulH is _still_ correct that there are other families of solutions not obeying the theorem, as I mentioned above: so, you're still wrong. I mean I know it sucks to find out that you're wrong, but ad-hoc crappy definitions are not going to save you from being wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $OD=c$ and the side lengths of the two squares $a$ and $b$. From right triangles OAB and OHF,

$$r^2=a^2+(a-c)^2;\>\>\>\>\> r^2=b^2+(b+c)^2$$

Eliminate $c$ to get,

$$a-\sqrt{r^2-a^2}=\sqrt{r^2-b^2}-b$$

Square both sides,

$$a\sqrt{ r^2-a^2} =b\sqrt{r^2-b^2}$$

Square again and rearrange,

$$r^2(a^2-b^2)=a^4-b^4$$

Thus, the sum of the two areas is

$$a^2+b^2=r^2=64$$

Answer (score 8):

A somewhat devious way is to extract the fact that the answer doesn't depend on where `D` is, so place it at the origin!

Then it's simply:

$$ x = y $$

$$ \therefore x^2 + y^2 = 2 x^2 = 8^2 $$

Comment: That is perhaps the neatest use of W.L.O.G I've seen, definitely using that as an example for why we can use it in future.

Comment: The "without loss of generality" is implicit in the phrasing of this question. A more devious question would be to ask what the _maximum_ area is (Still 64, but now you've got to prove it takes that value for |OD|<=|OA| )

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman This is a pretty terrible example of WLOG because it's not clear that the area is independent of D. Assuming it is works as a technique for contest math because you know that you've been given enough information to solve the problem, but in general making random assumptions like this will just lead to mistakes.

Comment: Given that no lengths are given obviously D is arbitrarily placed, so assuming AD = HD is completely fine.

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman It's obvious that D is arbitrarily placed. Is it obvious that the placement of D doesn't change the area?

Comment: @BradyGilg It's obvious only because we are only given the diameter *and* (as you say) we can assume there's a solution.  It would be very odd if we had to add a variable representing `D`'s position and give a solution based on that. As I said, this is all *somewhat devious*.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Let $V$ be the common vertex of our squares which lies on the diameter of the semicircle. We may assume that the coordinates of $V$ are $(x,0)$. The upper-right-corner $A$ is located at the intersection (the one with a positive ordinate) of $x^2+y^2=64$ and $y=x-v$. The upper-left-corner $B$ is located at the intersection (always the one with a positive ordinate) of $y=v-x$ and $x^2+y^2=64$. It follows that the ordinate of $A$ is $\frac{1}{2}\left(-v+\sqrt{128-v^2}\right)$ and the ordinate of $B$ is $\frac{1}{2}\left(v+\sqrt{128-v^2}\right)$. By summing the squares of these numbers we get that the total area of our squares is 
$$ \frac{1}{4}(v^2+128-v^2+v^2+128-v^2) = 64,$$
i.e. the area of a square built on a radius.

[image]

In order to produce an elementary proof, we just have to show that the length of $AB=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{AA'^2+BB'^2}$ does not depend on the position of $V$ on the diameter. But this is trivial since the symmetric of $B$ with respect to the diameter "sees" the $AB$-chord under an angle of $45^\circ$, such that $\widehat{AOB}$ always is a right angle (and $AOVB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Pythagorean theorem twice:
[image]

Comment: It needs to be mentioned why OB is perpendicular to OF.

Comment: @Narasimham Why is OB perpendicular to OF?

Comment: @personjerry,  if you continue $BD$ to meet $FH$ at $F′$ on the circle, you will see that thee angle $FF′B$ is $45°$.

Answer (score 1):

The base  $CA$ is partitioned into $(a,b)$ segments for the common squares corner **and $(b,a) $ for locating center of circle**.

To appreciate this direct analytical geometry is enough:

Equation of perpendicular bisector from the sketch:

$$\dfrac{ y-(a+b)/2}{x-(a+b)/2}= \dfrac{ (a+b)}{(a-b)}$$

At y=o, x=? Solving

[image]

$$ x_O=b $$

EDIT1:

*So in the construction all you need to find the center of circle is marking off segment length $b$ with a compass centered at $C$ and complete the circle through square outer vertices $(F,B)$ of required circle radius $R$ centered at $O$.*

Shown case is chosen $ (a=3,b=4)$ from familiar Pythagorean triplet with diameter of circle $10$ instead of $16$

$$ R^2= a^2+b^2 = R^2= 5^2 $$

The squares area sum equals area of square made on a side of radius $R$

Comment: Upvoting because this construction of the line equidistant from two points, and its point of intersection with the baseline that the two squares share, is really key for my understanding the possibilities here. You have three points B,C,F and this construction potentially creates three circles which can inscribe the two squares: one from this construction applied to {B, C}, one from it applied to {C, F}, one from it applied to {B, F}. It seems plausible that at any time only two of these lead to distinct inscriptions, but only the {B,F} one has the given property, if it is even valid.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  $C,A$ are ruled out from given problem geometry. I added edit about how to locate $0$

Answer (score 0):

1. We know the line between the semi circle and D exactly bisects each square, and thus FDB forms a right angle.
2. We know that for some angle FDM, the y coordinate at F is $sin \theta$
3. The right angle FDB then requires that the y coordinate for B is $sin (\theta + \pi/2) = cos \theta$
4. The area of each square is the square of those y coordinates, and thus the sum is $(r sin \theta)^2 + (r cos \theta)^2$
5. Given the identity $sin^2 \theta + cos^2 \theta = 1$, we can simplify the result to $r^2 = 64$.

Incidentally if you combine this approach for the unit circle with the Pythagorean approach in other answers, you have a neat proof of the trig identity we used. It also demonstrates that all such paths between points on a circle which form a right angle have equal length.

A simpler form is to note #1 as above, then:

2. All valid combinations of F and B form a right angle triangle with the same length hypotenuse.
3. The square of that hypotenuse is always the same as the required area by substituting for the squares' diagonals, and thus the result is constant.
4. If the result is constant it must equal the easy symmetric case and thus equals $r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of areas is not always 64.

Example : consider the square whose vertice are $O$, center of the semi-circle, $M_1 = (a, 0)$, $M_2=(a, a)$ and $M_3 = (0, a)$ with $a=4.\sqrt 2$. This square is inscribed in the semi-circle at $M_2$, its area is $a^2 = 32$.

Then consider the square whose vertice are $M_1$, $M_5=(a+b, 0)$, $M_6 = (a+b, b)$ and $M_7 = (a, b)$ with $b =2.\sqrt 6 - 2.\sqrt 2$. This square is inscribed in the semi-circle at $M_6$, its area is $b^2 = 32 -8.\sqrt 3$.

So the sum of the two area is $64-8.\sqrt 3$, different from 64.

As Phil H noticed, "*All the solutions given (and indeed the question, I suppose) assume that length OD <= length OA*". I find it very important to give demonstrations that give a response to the explicit question, implicit assumption are a way to non-sense.

Every answer given is wrong until you change the question : for example you could assert that the point of contact between the semi-circle and the square cannot be on the line $CD$.

Answer (score 0):

If we embed the bigger square with side $A$ into a coordinate system first quadrant and the smaller square with side $a$ adjacent to it we can easily see that the following four triangles are congruent:
$$((0,0),(a,0),(0,A))$$
$$((a,0),(A+a,0),(A+a,a))$$
$$((0,A),(A,A),(A,A+a))$$
$$((A,a),(A+a,a),(A,A+a)).$$ From this, it also follows that $((a,0),(0,A),(A,A+a),(A+a,a))$ has equal diagonals $((a,0),(A,A+a))$ and $((0,A),(A+a,a)).$

Hence, they form a new square with area $r^2$. As the coset of the new square, with the sum of the bigger and smaller squares extended with exactly two of these congruent triangles, gives exactly the new square on one hand and the sum of the bigger and smaller squares on the other hand hence $r^2=A^2+a^2$ follows.